# SQLite query dramatically slower with System.Data.SQLite (C#) than in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that runs several joins on the same table. It's joining on a `SessionID` which is a key that does not represent a column in the table, but is generated as `new column` via substring operations (please also see the query code below).

Accordingly, I cannot proactively create an index on SessionID, because that column does not exist in the relevant table `Logs`.

However, when I am running the query in SQLiteStudio (v3.1.1), the query runs quite fast. When I run explain query plan in SQLiteStudio I do see the following output:

```
1   0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)

2   0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)

0   0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)

0   1   1   SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS b USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (SessionID=?)

0   2   2   SEARCH SUBQUERY 2 AS c USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (SessionID=?)
```

**As we can see, SQLite is using an automatic covering index SessionID.**

When running the same query from my C# via System.Data.SQLite against the same database, the query is dramatically slower (about 50 times).

When I run explain query plan in C# I do see the follwing output:

```
7   0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
14  0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
48  0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
```

**Please note, that there is no automatic covering index being used.**

I tried using Analyze and also explicitely set automatic_index= true for the SQLite connection, but it did not impact the query plan.

The SQLite query is:

```
select a.username, a.PSMID, a.PSMHost, a.AccountName, A.TargetHost, a.TargetUser, 
  Case When info2 Not like '%DataBase=%' Then '' Else substr(info2, instr(info2, 'DataBase=') +9, (instr(info2, ';Dst') +- instr(info2, 'DataBase=') - 9)) End as TargetDataBase, a.ConnectionComponent, a.StartTime, 
  Case when c.time is not null then c.time else b.EndTime end as EndTime, 
  Case when c.SessionDuration is not null then c.SessionDuration else b.SessionDuration end as SessionDuration, 
  Case When c.RequestReason not like '%PSMSR169E%' and c.RequestReason != '' then 'Yes' else 'No' End as ErrorOccurred, 
  Case When c.RequestReason like '%PSMSR169E%' Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End as DurationElapsed, c.RequestReason As Message  
from (SELECT info2, time as StartTime, username, replace(info1,'Root\','') as AccountName, 
  Case When info2 not like '%;DataBase=%' Then substr(info2, instr(info2, 'ApplicationType=') +16 , instr(info2, ';Dst') -17) Else substr(info2, instr(info2, 'ApplicationType=') +16 , instr(info2, ';DataBase=') -17) 
  End as ConnectionComponent, substr(info2, instr(info2, 'DstHost=') +8, (instr(info2, ';Pro') +- instr(info2, 'DstHost=') - 8)) as TargetHost, substr(info2, instr(info2, 'User=') +5, length(info2) - instr(info2, 'User=') -5) as TargetUser, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'PSMID=') +6, (instr(info2, ';Session') - instr(info2, 'PSMID=') - 6)) as PSMID, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SessionID=') +10, (instr(info2, ';Src') - instr(info2, 'SessionID=') -10)) as SessionID, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SrcHost=') +8, (instr(info2, ';User') - instr(info2, 'SrcHost=') -8)) as PSMHost, 
     Null as SessionDuration from logs 
where code in (300) and info2 != 0) a left join (select time as EndTime,
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SessionDuration=') +16, (instr(info2, ';SessionID') - instr(info2, 'SessionDuration=') - 16)) as SessionDuration, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SessionID=') +10, (instr(info2, ';Src') - instr(info2, 'SessionID=') -10)) as SessionID 
from logs 
where code in (302) and info2 != 0) b on a.SessionID = b.SessionID left join (Select 'Yes' as PSMDisconnectFailed, time, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SessionID=') +10, (instr(info2, ';Src') - instr(info2, 'SessionID=') -10)) as SessionID, 
     substr(info2, instr(info2, 'SessionDuration=') +16, (instr(info2, ';SessionID') - instr(info2, 'SessionDuration=') - 16)) as SessionDuration, RequestReason 
 from logs where code in (303) and info2 != 0) c on a.SessionID = C.SessionID
```

Anyone has an idea how to further troubleshoot/investigate this issue?

EDIT #1: I am using the following command for establishing the connection in my C# code:

```
        public static SQLiteConnection connectToDB()
    {
        dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = data\\LOGS.db; Version = 3;");
        dbConnection.Open();
        return dbConnection;
    }
```

Edit #2: After upgrading SQLite Studio (now using SQLite version 3.24.0), I am seeing the same explain query plan output as with the System.Data.SQLite SQLit v3.27.0 version. **Note: "AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX" parts are now missing as well.**

```
7   0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
14  0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
48  0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
```

Comment: What versions of sqlite are the two programs using (they might not be the same, though based on that EQP output both are older ones).

Comment: And can you reformat your post so that select is readable and not one huge long line?

Comment: Hi @Shawn. When running the command "select sqlite_version();" - I am seeing the following outputs:

SQLiteStudio: 3.15.0
C# Code: 3.27.2

I am using System.Data.SQLite 1.0.110 and SQLite Studio v3.1.1.

Comment: Hi @Shawn . I updated SQLite Studio and I am seeing now the following output when running "select sqlite_version();": 3.24.0

Also, since the update, the explain query plan now looks exactly same to what I can see for the C# 3.27.2 query plan:

0 0 SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
0 0 SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
0 0 SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)

Note: The "SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 AS b USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (SessionID=?)" parts are missing here now as well.

Comment: You can find online tools to nicely format SQL to be human readable. There are some things in changelogs between the two versions that *might* apply, but your query as you have it now is still an unreadable mess that I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting: Once I converted the query to a view and run `select * from myview` the query was very fast. Explain query plan has now the following output:

```
id  parent  notused detail
3   0   0   MATERIALIZE 2
7   3   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
44  0   0   MATERIALIZE 3
48  44  0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
92  0   0   SEARCH TABLE logs USING INDEX i_Logs (Code=?)
112 0   0   SEARCH SUBQUERY 2 AS b USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (SessionID=?)
140 0   0   SEARCH SUBQUERY 3 AS c USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (SessionID=?)
157 0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
259 0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

I am not sure why the EQP has changed when I am using a view instead, but I am very happy now because it's working great and very fast :-)

Thanks a lot @Carlos Cavero for formatting my code.